# Getting different results when calling the same (self written) method

Tags: java, set, self

First off, sorry the tittle is super descriptive, but I honestly couldn't come up with a way to explain my issue in one sentence.
To explain what I'm doing: I am creating an alphabet that has a key at the beginning for mono alphabetic encryption. I made a method that removed duplicates which works fine. I have some extra time for this assingment so I have been playing around. I discovered Sets, which don't contain duplicates.

So when I have the Set return to a string, I have a string that reads

> [s, e, c, u, r.....x, y, z]

The string has all these characters in it I don't need. So I use a method I wrote that removes anything thats not a letter. When I call it the first time, I get

> s e c u r....x y z

I, just for fun, call the method again. I am now left with

> secur....xyz

So if any one can tell me why the method is successful in removing the commas and the brackets the first time but not the spaces yet removes the spaces in a second call, that would be awesome.
For reference, my code

```
public static String createMonoAlphabet(String key){
    String crypticAlphabet = key;       
    crypticAlphabet = crypticAlphabet.concat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    //crypticAlphabet = removeDuplicates(crypticAlphabet);
    Set alphabet = new LinkedHashSet();
    for(int i = 0; i<crypticAlphabet.length(); i++){
        alphabet.add(crypticAlphabet.charAt(i));
    }

    crypticAlphabet = alphabet.toString();
    crypticAlphabet = parseInput(crypticAlphabet);
    crypticAlphabet = parseInput(crypticAlphabet);
    return crypticAlphabet;
}
```

That is the method that uses the set. As a note, I've never used them before I'm just playing around here so if its bad practice or something thats fine. Feel free to let me know, but I'm not as concerned about that right now
And now for the method that removes non letters

```
    public static String parseInput(String input){
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(input);

    for(int i = 0; i < buf.length(); i++){
        char c = buf.charAt(i);
        if(!(((int)c >= 65 && (int)c <= 90) || 
                ((int)c >= 97 && (int)c <= 122))){
            System.out.print(buf.charAt(i));
            buf =  buf.deleteCharAt(i);
        }   
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    System.out.println();
    input = buf.toString();
    return input;
}
```

Comment: You should post the code of your `parseInput` method.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Thought I did. I just copied the wrong bit. Its up there now.

Answer (score 2):

Few remarks on your `parseInput` code:

- You are iterating thought your StringBuffer and modify it at the same time (by calling `deleteCharAt(i)`). Doing this kind of things is often a bad idea.
- In Java you shouldn't do low level operations like casting a char to his ASCII value (it's look like C code)

In my opinion the best way to solve your problem is by using a regular expression. I would have wrote something like that:

```
public static String parseInput(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
}
```

It means replace everything which is not a letter by an empty String.
Welcome on SO!

Comment: Faster, nicer and more simple than others answers.

Comment: I love regular expressions, and I played around with them initially. but I couldn't seem to get them to work. I think I tried to use them for something more complicated and gave up. That however seems far more simple. Also, thanks for the welcome!

Comment: If I had even more time I'd probably go through and re write a lot more of this code. There are a lot of things I know are bad practice (so much static!). I have some extra time, but not quite that much!

Answer (score 1):

The alphabet.toString() call adds all the characters you don't need. The String representation of a set is always:

> [ item1, item2, item3, ... ]

To convert the set to a String again, iterate over it and use a StringBuilder to create the String, e.g.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s: alphabet) { builder.append(s); }
crypticAlphabet = builder.toString();
```

Comment: I don't think this is the real issue here.  I tested this and still need multiple parses under certain conditions.

Comment: This is the way you should answer the bigger question.  There is no reason you should dumb the string into a data structure like a set, then call toString on that set, then parse that string again.  Even if you need to do additional filtering, you should use this mechanism.  You might consider a regular expression rather than pseudo-ASCII filtering.  Use a character class for word characters.

Comment: Yeah, I'm well aware I'm going about this in some pretty sub-par ways. I'm semi new to programming and I enjoy coming up with bad ideas, and slowly realising new and better ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invert the order of the for loop in the `parseInput` method.
When doing a `deleteCharAt` you provoke a left shift meaning you will miss certain characters.  Inverting the order fixes this.

Try the following for your for loop:

`for (int i = buf.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Crazy. I don't think I ever would have realised that. Thanks.

Comment: There's a deeper problem in the algorithm, I explained the details. This change will save you only for these exceptional case.

Comment: @Luiggi, what you explain in your post is actually what I mean with a left shift and hence missing some characters.  But thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @tom I'm not saying your solution is wrong, it works. But IMO you should avoid modifying an array when you're reading the values inside it, I preffer to use a temporal variable to hold the *good* values and not touch the original data :).

Answer (score 0):

To solve your actual problem, I changed your `parseInput` method for a simpler solution:

```
public static String parseInput(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if ((chars[i] >= 65 && chars[i] <= 90) ||
            (chars[i] >= 97 && chars[i] <= 122)) {
            sb.append(chars[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You had a problem in your late code: It is not good to remove an element from an array using the index and then moving to the next index. This will be a sample using the String `[s, e]` (including white spaces):

First time, you'll have this array (shorter form):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
[ s ,   e ]
```

Index is 0, found a `[` that is a non-character, so it will be removed, having the actual array

```
0 1 2 3 4
s ,   e ]
```

Check that the elements went back one position in the array, but your index will roll up by 1, so now Index is 1 and found `,` (not `s`!). This will be the output for that case:

```
0 1 2 3
s   e ]
```

Now your index will be 2. Check that the white space moved back 1 position and became 1. That's why your algorithm fails.

As side notes, you should consider these advices:

- When using a Collection, define the class for the container. In this case, you will use `Set<Character>` and `LinkedHashSet<Character>`.
- Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. More about it [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/08/stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer.html).